# Consultar produtos com ajax e php para pagina de vendas

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, xampp

estou tentando criar um pequeno sistema de vendas para uma loja local e estou com problema na página de vendas, estava tentando aprender a utilizar o ajax para consultar dados do produto no banco mysql do xampp e então retornar o valor e nome do produto, para poder depois colocar a quantidade que está sendo vendida e somar com os outros produtos que o cliente está levando e no fim atualizar a quantidade no banco de dados, porem não estou conseguindo puxar os dados do banco de dados.
Gostaria de um auxilio para poder ver qual o erro no código.
[![O codigo apresenta um warning dizendo que undefined array key "codigoBarra"][1]][1]

Vendas

## Venda

Codigo De Barra:
                
                
            
        
    


    recuperarProduto = () =>{
        var produto = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var codigoBarra = document.getElementById("codigoBarra").value;
        var resltado = document.getElementById("resultado");
        produto.open("POST"+"venda.php?codigoBarra="+codigoBarra, true);

```
    if(produto.readyState == 4){

        if(produto.status == 200){
            result.innerHTML = xmlreq.responseText;
         }
         else{
             result.innerHTML = "Erro: " + xmlreq.statusText;
         }
        }
        produto.send("venda.php");
    };
```

`include('conecta.php');

$codigoBarra = $_POST['codigoBarra'];

$sql = "select nome, valor from produto where codigoDeBarra = ?";
$resultado = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$resultado->execute();
$vetor=$resultado->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
foreach($vetor as $linha){
    echo $linha->nome."--".$linha->valor;
}`

?>

Aqui está o codigo html, javascript e php que estou utilizando.
o banco de dados utilizado é o mysql do phpmyadmin.
estrutura da tabela:
id_produto int not null auto_increment,
CodigoDeBarra varchar,
nome varchar,
quantidade int,
valor double.

Se caso alguem puder ajudar serei muito grato !
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/auF45.png

Comment: O código está completo? Pelo q parece você não está passando a variável `$codigoBarra` para a sua query. Está faltando `$resultado->bindValue()` provavelmente. Dê uma olhada [aqui](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.bindvalue.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No seu próprio exemplo o erro está implicito do seu problema que ele não tá achando o index 'codigoDeBarra'.

Nunca se deve utilizar acessores diretamente se seu array / objecto é totalmente mutável e dinamico.

Então pensasse que seria melhor fazer

```
   if (isset($array['codigoDeBarras']) {
     /// faz algo
    } else {
 // faz algo se o indice não existe
}
```

[No PHP 8 tem funções excelentes como o match que pode simplificar seu codigo também](https://www.google.com/search?q=php%20match&oq=php%20match&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.1295j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).